# How to calculate number of days between from currentdate to anotherdate using mongoose aggregate function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The below code only return,the below format

```
Opp.aggregate( [ { $project: { item: 1, day: { $subtract: [ new Date(), new Date("$CreateDate") ] } } } ] , function (err, result) {
             console.log(err);
             console.log(result);
            res.send(result);
            });

[
  {
    "_id": "56569bff5fa4f203c503c792",
    "day": 1449031701920
  }
]
```

but i need to get only day difference.please give some solution to solve my problem.

Comment: why don't you divide the end result with number of seconds in a day?

Comment: i dont know, how to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      item: 1,
      day: { $divide: [{ $subtract: [
              new Date(),
              "$CreateDate"
            ]
          },
          86400000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Code snippet to change input collection CreateDate in ISO format, assuming col is the collection name:

```
db.col.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc.CreateDate = new Date(doc.CreateDate);
    db.col.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {CreateDate: doc.CreateDate}});
});
```

Whenever you insert or update documents into this collection make sure you are inserting the CreateDate in ISO format. Since you are using mongoose define CreateDate as a string in schema, and try to pass javascript date object for this field.

Comment: my createDate is "2015-11-30 00:00:00" and today date is "2015-12-03 00:00:00" i want total diiferent day is 2, but the above code i didn't get expected result..

Comment: What result did you get? Also is your CreateDate in ISO format?

Comment: [
  {
    "_id": "56569bff5fa4f203c503c792",
    "day": 16771.231748506943
  }
]

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your CreateDate or your system date. CreateDate needs to be in ISO format. Also from your initial result you got days as 1449031701920. Converting this into number of days will get 16771.2. Most probably it will be the problem with CreateDate. Can you post a sample document as it is from the collection?

Comment: my create date is string format...how to convert string format to ISODate format...my sample document is below format,

Comment: {

    "_id":{
        "$oid":"56569bff5fa4f203c503c792"
    },
    "CreateDate":"2013-06-03 00:00:00"

}

Comment: new Date("2013-06-03") gives ISODate("2013-06-03T00:00:00Z"). If you need the hour minute and second information then use like new Date("2013-06-03 00:00:00") You must change all CreateDate to ISO format like this in input document. A sample code snippet is shown below